# PBKDF2 java script implementation with Apache License

Tags: javascript, pbkdf2

I searched a lot and could not find any PBKDF2 JavaScript implementation that has the Apache License, does it exist or must I implement it by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it now, to solve my problem I can use the WebCrypto APIs for JavaScript. An explanation on how to use it can be found [here](http://blog.engelke.com/2015/02/14/deriving-keys-from-passwords-with-webcrypto/#comment-3476)

Comment: Almost certainly there's no good reason to need PBKDF2 in the browser.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your affirmation?

Comment: I can only be very abstract without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, but the browser is an untrusted environment and performing a hash/key derivation function is a trusted action. If, for instance, you're trying to verify a user password, what is to stop a user from bypassing the verification and just passing back "success" to the server?

Comment: I never talked about using a server, it's all clientside

Comment: You never talked about *anything* you're actually doing. I maintain my assertion that it is, under most circumstances, inappropriate to do this in the browser. I can't know whether your situation fits under most circumstances or is the rare exception.